# Azure Batch re-queue failed tasks

Tags: python, azure-batch

Sometimes tasks might fail due to unforeseen circumstances, such as opening a file that a task(s) needed access to and locking the file.

I would, in such a case, like to simply be able to re-queue my failed task.

How can I re-queue failed tasks in Azure Batch (Python3 or Portal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by requeue in this context is trying to re-run the fail task:

You can set the `batch_client.config.retry_policy.retries`

SDK doc: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/azure-sdk-for-python/v2.0.0rc2/azure-sdk-for-python.pdf

Sample code:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/Python/Batch/sample1_helloworld.py#L108